# Retrieving a specific data

Tags: objective-c

I am new to xcode.. and I would love to learn about retrieving data from XML.. This is a draft code that I have been stucked with for days.. I manage to display a list of XML codes

XML CODE:

```
<find>
<set_number>038881</set_number>
<no_records>000138874</no_records>
<no_entries>000007000</no_entries>
</find>
```

However, now I have some difficulties in retrieving only the set_number from this xml... The URL I have left it blank due to confidential purposes.. so dont mind about it.. The last two codes has resulted my app to force close.. Help!!

```
 NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

 NSMutableData *receivedData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] ]autorelease];            
 NSString *theRecord = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

  NSString *path = [theRecord valueForKey: @"set_number"];
     NSLog(@"File Data: %@", path);
```

I tried to add in this code at the bottom instead..

```
   if ([theRecord isEqualToString:@"no_records"]){ 

        NSLog(@"Contents of URL: %@", theRecord); 
}
```

Then I also trying to debug my codes.. No error shown.. instead they display 0 for the output.. and I am wondering is it because my no_records is an integer?? But I have assign the record as a string.. is that why they couldnt display?

---

I tried to add in this code at the bottom instead..

```
   `if ([theRecord isEqualToString:@"no_records"]){ 

        NSLog(@"Contents of URL: %@", theRecord); 
}`
```

Then I also trying to debug my codes.. No error shown.. instead they display 0 for the output.. and I am wondering is it because my no_records is an integer?? But I have assign the record as a string.. is that why they couldnt display?? Please help!!

Comment: Not an answer, but surely you should be defining *path BEFORE trying to NSLOG it.

Comment: Yeap!! Was eager to post the question till I foresee that mistake! Edited it already! Thanks Richard(:

Comment: I did the last two codes below and I got this error... Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x887d000> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key set_number.' Not sure what this means.. Can anybody explain this to me ??

Answer (score 0):

To parse your XML use the NSXMLParser class.

Comment: am i suppose to make use of initWithData??

Comment: Or in your case, just use initWithContentsOfURL to simplify your code. Seee http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248883/Objective-C-Fundamentals-NSXMLParser for an example.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *path = [theRecord valueForKey: @"set_number"];

theRecord is a NSString instance that can not use valueForKey.
You should parse your xml string first and get the content you want from tag.
Or you should get substring in your string.